# App listening to multiple UUID's

Tags: ios, uuid, monitor, ibeacon

Is it possible for an ios App to listen to multiple UUID's? Specifically for apples iBeacon technology.

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"23542266-18D1-4FE4-B4A1-23F8195B9D39"];
    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"com.devfright.myRegion"];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
```

Using this code one could start monitoring the following uuid: 23542266-18D1-4FE4-B4A1-23F8195B9D39, if I would add another class listening to another uuid, would this work, wouldn't there be any interference? Maybe add several more listeners?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can listen up to 20 UUIDs per app. Simply create more `CLBeaconRegion`s, and call `startMonitoringForRegion:` for each region you want to monitor. You only need a single `CLLocationManager` to do this.

Note that you will get a call to `didEnterRegion:` / `didExitRegion:` for *each* region you are monitoring. The `region` parameter will tell you which region you have entered.

Number of UUID limit source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW2

Comment: Ok, because the problem i saw with iBeacon, you would have to install an app for each shop/museum/... you are going to go to receive notifications, if there would exist an app where one could register your UUID's with information to show, then you would only have to install one app. Thank you.

Comment: You can listen up to 20 different UUID's per app. "Core Location limits to 20 the number of regions that may be simultaneously monitored by a single app."
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW2